# Saving a list's size without updating it

Tags: java, android, list

So I am trying to make it so that when a user creates a game, the game ID is just the current size of the List the game is stored in.

This is what I am using right now to determine the game ID

```
private int gameSlot() {
        gameSlot = openGames.size();
    return gameSlot;
}
```

And that works fine, but the problem is, when a second user creates a game, the first game that was made has it's game ID updated to the updated size of the list, so the first and second game have the same ID.

How can I make it so that when the size of the list is updated, the game ID of the game does not change?

This is what I am using to assign the game ID.

```
gameMaker = new GameMaker(hp.uid, userName, amount, gameSlot());
```

Comment: How do you know that the second game has the same ID as the first? Are you calling gameSlot() again? Instead, store the ID in a new field in GameMaker (say, GameMaker.id) and then see if GameMaker.id is different for the two games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the previous value as well use :

```
 gameSlot = gameSlot + openGames.size();
```

So every time you add a new list size, the previous value is never going to get lost.

Comment: Thank you, I did something similar based off of your advice. What I did was made gameSlot = openGames.size() and then when a user makes a new game I just incremented the value by one so I did gameSlot++ instead of calling gameSlot() each time.